# Bats testing command output not completely captured

Tags: bash, testing, command-line-interface

### Context

While testing a `keepass2` installation procedure using `bats` testing in bash, I noticed that the output of a command in terminal differs from the output that is captured in a `bats` test. In terminal the command `keepass2 --version` returns:

```
Gtk-Message: 15:29:44.377: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
KeePass 2.45
Copyright © 2003-2020 Dominik Reichl
```

Whereas the test output of the following test:

```
@test "Checking keepass2 version responds with Failed to load module canberra-gtk-module." {
    COMMAND_OUTPUT=$(keepass2 --version)

    EXPECTED_OUTPUT='Gtk-Message: 15:29:44.377: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
KeePass 2.45
Copyright © 2003-2020 Dominik Reichl'

    assert_equal "$COMMAND_OUTPUT" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

is:

```
✗ Checking keepass2 version responds with: Failed to load module canberra-gtk-module.
   (from function `assert_equal' in file test/post_setup/../../test/libs/bats-assert/src/assert.bash, line 91,
    in test file test/post_setup/test_apt_install_keepass2_postsetup.bats, line 68)
     `assert_equal "$COMMAND_OUTPUT" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"' failed
   Gtk-Message: 15:51:27.775: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
   /home/a/Documents/git/Productivity-setup/test/post_setup/../../test/libs/bats-assert/src/assert.bash: line 65: [: KeePass 2.45
   Copyright © 2003-2020 Dominik Reichl: binary operator expected
   
   -- values do not equal --
   expected (3 lines):
     Gtk-Message: 15:29:44.377: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
     KeePass 2.45
     Copyright © 2003-2020 Dominik Reichl
   actual (2 lines):
     KeePass 2.45
     Copyright © 2003-2020 Dominik Reichl
   --
```

So the `bats` test thinks the output of the command only contains the last 2 lines of the command line output of the same command, whereas I would expect bats to capture the full 3 lines of output that I see in the command line when running `keepass2 --version`.

### Question

How can I capture the `Gtk-Message: 15:29:44.377: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` line that is shown in the command line for command `keepass2 --version`, in the bats test?

### Note

This is question is not about the xy-problem of how to solve the `canberra-gtk-module` warning. It is also not about how to make a test that passes while that warning `canberra` warning is thrown. This question is about how to catch that warning from the `version` command in a bats test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is likely not *stdout* but *stderr*

```
Gtk-Message: 15:29:44.377: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

---

This line captures only *stdout* into the *variable*.

```
COMMAND_OUTPUT=$(keepass2 --version)
```

Removing the first line from your `EXPECTED_OUTPUT` should fix it.

(The error is inconsequential for checking version, so it can be ignored in the test)

---

#### To capture stdout *and* stderr

```
COMMAND_ERR_OUT=$(keepass2 --version 2>&1)
```

#### To capture stderr *only*

```
COMMAND_ERR=$(keepass2 --version 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @kevinnls, I have included a note to further clarify  my question, based on your answer. I did not convey  clearly enough that the test is about catching that warning in a bats test.